# iMacros code to search and find a work in a page and then send a message if that word exists in that page

Tags: javascript, search, extract, imacros

I am trying to write a code in Imacros. What I am trying to do is,see if a string of words exist in a page, if it does, not ,then go to next page. If it does, then send a message (I have working code for this, so no worries here).

I have two pieces of iim extension code, one is for clicking next button and another for clicking certain buttons to send message.

Only the first action, clicking next page, is always being done currently, even if the condition is satisfying

The code is always executing the first action(clicking next page)it never seems to go to the else statement (sending message), even if the condition satisfies.

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";

macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=TITLE ATTR=TXT:Person<SP>is<SP>online,<SP>in<SP>India EXTRACT=TXT";

iimPlay(macro);

if (iimGetLastExtract(0) == "#EANF#") {
    iimPlay('next_page.iim');
    iimGetLastExtract(0);
}else{
    iimPlay('Message Sending.iim');
    iimGetLastExtract(0);
};
```

Comment: There is a `TITLE` tag in your macro. So, are you searching the necessary text on the page or in the page title?